# Sed command not working, error: cannot open

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I'm trying to find a file called data which is made up of xml documents and I'm stripping the xml tags and putting the output into a file called dataPP. However my command is giving me the error:

sed: cant read dataPP/sh: no such file or directory.

I'm not sure why it's trying to go into the path sh but it shouldn't be trying to.

Heres my command.

```
find data -type f -name '*.xml' -exec sh -c 'file="$0" sed -i "s/<[^>]*>//g" $HOME/dataPP/$0 '{} ';'
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `$0` should expand to? Why do you assign to `file` when it is referenced nowhere?

Comment: instead of putting the results in another folder I just overwrited the current folder and it worked